# iOS / Xcode / Objective C / PHP / Rest - iPhone authenticate with PHP scripts

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, rest

Im slowly learning about developing an iPhone app for my website ... I have read alot of tutorials and also quite a bit on the apple developer section.

When i started, i asked a question 'what would be the best way to interact with my web app' and i got the answer of RESTful services, so i installed restful on my php app, thats all working good and im happy with that.

My web app is a membership system and i want people to authenticate with the current web app on their iphone, if they have an account, great, let them in, if they dont have one, then display the error msg.

I am getting a little confused though and im wondering if someone could help me.

I dont want anyone to be able to view responses from the restful service, so i take it i implement keys, now, does each user on the system require their own key for their iphone app to access the rest api and if so, how do i run authentication if they need a key first?

or, does the app only require one key to access the api and then everything else is done through the user authentication ... if that is so, one key would surely be not that hard to crack and is it possible for people to disassemble the app to reveal the api key to access the api?

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated ... or even samples of how people deal with authentication and rest services in php and ios.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Better get cozy with (the now deprecated) `ASIHTTPRequest`, or NSURL... Classes.  Also, Xcode is an IDE, not a language.

Comment: Hi! I`m learning iphone development too right now. The simplest way to interact with your site is use UIWebView to display your site, and use  [myView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString@"this_is_js_function();" to call js from objective-c.If you want to call objective-c method from site use fake protocol in your links like "fake://myMethod/param1:param2:param3 and parse it on request delegated method

Comment: @kirugan — you must be kidding.

Comment: Here is the proof: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html and this http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Comment: @kirugan why do u want to use javascript?

Comment: @vikingosegundo my solution is not for performance reason, its just fast way to make application for your website.

Comment: @kirugan Restful APIs are clearly not websites.

Comment: Lol, wow I wish there was a down vote on comments

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would probably build an authentication service.  With this the user can make a call to the auth service using user/password or whatever authentication criteria you have.  You can than either authorize or deny the user access to the REST services.  If authenticated, you would pass a token back to the caller in the app.  Subsequent calls to the main REST API, would need to include this authentication token, which you would authenticate against currently valid token for the user before deciding whether to provide a response via the REST service.

Comment: wow that sounds difficult .. So you would build a little function that just checks the user credentials, wont that open another route of attack if someone found it?

Comment: I am using this approach a lot. +1. It is wuite easy to code, the token generation should be fast. (uuid, hashed timestamp, … what ever). The client side adapter can handle the token transparently by setting the token as an header value for every request. One thing missing: You should always use encryption, ie SSL/TLS

Comment: Ok, so a good way to do what im looking for is to create a url that accepts username/password, if its correct it returns a api key, then thats stored in the app ... everytime a request is made to the api, that users key is  used ... am i understanding this right? sorry about the questions, im a little confused - also, when a user signs up to the website, that user should automatically get a api key generated?

Comment: the credentials belong in the body of a post request (json), the server should answer with a json object in the response body. from then on you could add the token/api key as a HTTP header value. or you put it in any request body.

Comment: I figured out another way ... have different levels of access to the API, i set one level to only access the authentication, and another level for everything else :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your key, sha1 or whatever the algorithm of your liking is. Make sure your web service is accessible via https only, then embed the key into your request header. Yes ASIHTTPRequest is depreciated however AFNetworking is a great replacement https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. On your PHP side ensure the auth key in your header is valid first, if so then further procede to validate the username and password passed via POST. This should get you on your way, I can post code tomorrow if you still need help...

---

### Updated - added code below

Try this...

```
// setup httpClient
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.yourWebsite.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];  
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

// setup required wsapi parameters
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setObject:username_ forKey:@"username"];
[parameters setObject:password_ forKey:@"password"];
request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/path/to/your/webservice/authFile.php" parameters:parameters];

// setup request headers
[request setValue:@"68489233957fd9028kd9adf40119c1c93a98c00b80h94lk2jsdo9234720" forHTTPHeaderField:@"wsapiAccessToken"];  

// setup request operation blocks
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [json_ parseJSONResponse:operation.responseData];

    // do something with your response here...
    }  

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // handle error

}];

[operation start];
```

On your server side use something like this using PHP...

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wsapi/functions/authFunctions.php');

if(accessTokenIsValid())
{
    if((isset($_POST['username'])) && (isset($_POST['password'])))
    {
        // validate passed username and password and do whatever else you need to do.
        // be sure to respond back with something so that your app can do something 
        // useful with the response like give access to the app on success or show 
        // an error message on failure
    }
    else
    {
        $responseArray = array('authResponse'=>'__PARAMSERROR__');
        echo json_encode($responseArray);
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $responseArray = array('authResponse'=>'__AUTHERROR__');
    echo json_encode($responseArray);
    exit;
}
```

?>

Note that I use a function here called `accessTokenIsValid` which is shown below.

```
function getWsapiAccessToken()
{
    $tokenString = "Some string here";
    // add some salt if you like - make this harder to guess
    return sha1($tokenString);
}
function accessTokenIsValid() 
{
    if( $_SERVER['HTTP_WSAPIACCESSTOKEN'] == getWsapiAccessToken() )
    {
            return true;
    }
    else
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you wouldnt mind, that would be great ... im getting all confused hahaha ... Thank you so much

Comment: Was the code I posted helpful?